# Adding a library to an MFC project

Tags: c++, mfc, static-linking

So this might be super basic, but that's what happens when you get a job you aren't wholly qualified for, right?

I've got an MFC project, everything is working great, but I'm trying to add the string and stringstream directive into the project.

No matter where I put `#include <string>` and `#include <sstream>` I get the  "string: undeclared identifier" error.

Thanks in advance? :D

Comment: Your first sentence is quite disturbing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try std::string instead of string, since string is in the std namespace

Comment: Correct. Prefer explicit namespace resolution. However since this is an MFC project why not just use `CString`?

Answer (score 3):

Concerning that topic of this is

> Adding a library to an MFC project

and I was searching for solution how to add dll to MFC project I will add here solution as time saver for all of you...

If you want to reference library you need 3 files:

1. LibraryName.h
2. LibraryName.lib
3. LibraryName.dll

Follow steps:

1. Add all these to you solution.
2. In your application file add header file using #include "LibraryName.h"
3. Click right mouse button on your project and chose "References"
4. Go to Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input
5. In field Additional Dependencies write "LibraryName.lib", you can also check Ignore All Default Libraries to No

Compile and Have Fun!